# Why do I have some objects without UV menu?

Tags: uv

As you can see in the images, I have several platonic solids created with the math function.
The cylinder of course is just a common mesh, and it is the only one with a UV set.
The problem is: I can't find a menu to ADD a UV set to the platonic models meshes.
I would expect to find it in the UV menu, but that's lacking as well...
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

To add a UV set, go to EDIT MODE, hit U and click UNWRAP in the menu.

However, I must say that adding the option to the UV menu would be more intuitive.